# Core Data and undo groups

Tags: ios, core-data, nsundomanager

I'm working with Core Data for the first time and this has me stumped.

I have the following methods to handle grouping my changes and saving them:

```
- (void)beginUndoGrouping:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSLog(@"begin");
    [managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
    [managedObjectContext.undoManager beginUndoGrouping];
}

- (void)endUndoGroupingAndSaveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSLog(@"end/save");
    [managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
    [managedObjectContext.undoManager endUndoGrouping];
    [self saveContext:managedObjectContext];
}

- (void)cancelUndoGrouping:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSLog(@"cancel");
    [managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
    [managedObjectContext.undoManager endUndoGrouping];
    [managedObjectContext.undoManager undoNestedGroup];
}
```

Aided by the NSLog statements I know this is the sequence of events:

- start app in root view
- enter list view
  **begin**
- leave list view
  **end/save**
- enter item detail view
- enter category detail view
  **begin**
- touch Add Category button, which takes us to another view
  **begin**
- enter new data
- touch Done button
  **end/save**
- touch Back to go back to item detail view
- touch Cancel button
  **cancel**
- go back to list view
  **begin**

At this point my new Category is gone and I don't understand why.  It was wrapped in a group, which was ended and saved.  Shouldn't it be immune from being rolled back at that point?  I would have expected the cancel to only affect any changes made in the item detail view.  And if the way it's behaving now is correct, then how do I make it behave the way I was expecting?

Any clarification would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be that you need to use a second  managed object context for the inner group.

Comment: Could you post the code you got as the final answer? I'm not sure what you mean about the second managed object context.